# How to host IdentityServer on IIS instead of Kestrel?

Tags: iis, identityserver4

I just got my IdentityServer working with quickstart code. What I want to do now is to host the server in IIS, not Kestrel, as it does in quickstart code by default. I tried changing some of the settings in launchSettings.json but couldn't figure out how to get it to work. Is there any doc/instructions for how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Kestrel is always used, regardless of IIS. With IIS, then IIS is just a proxy forwarding the requests to Kestrel and ISS is also adding some extra functionality that Kestrel does not provide. As an alternative you can use [HTTP.SYS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/httpsys?view=aspnetcore-3.1) as an alternative to Kestrel. But that is independent of the use of ISS or not.

Comment: Thanks Tore for your input! Sorry that my question was unclear - I actually understand the relationship between IIS and Kestrel (I think you are the one who pointed that out to me sometime ago). What I am looking to achieve now is to add IIS to host my IdentityServer (understanding that behind the sense it is still Kestrel provides the service). Now I have everything working by "self-hosting" (Kestrel), what do I need to do to add IIS on top of it? Because that will be our target environment for production.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should know the difference between kestrel and iis，Kestrel is a full blown web server. You can run your ASP.NET Core application using just Kestrel. In your ASP.NET application, probably in the wwwroot directory, you'll see In your ASP.NET application, probably in the wwwroot directory, you'll see a web.config that contains this in the web.config, Essentially, what this does is forward all requests to Kestrel. IIS will not run ASP.NET themselves anymore. Instead, they will act as proxies that simply pass requests and responses back and forth from Kestrel.

More information about kestrel and iis you can refer to this link: [Kestrel vs IIS](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/25/kestrel-vs-iis/)

Comment: Thanks again! I will read the article and see if I can figure out how to get what I need...

Comment: If you have any questions, please let me know.